# How can I connect the labels in my DetailViewController to show the information that I'm extracting from Parse in EventCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
EventCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventCell"
                         forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"EventCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.eventName.text = object[@"name"];
cell.eventInformation.text = object[@"details"];
cell.creatorName.text = object[@"creatorName"];


return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];

//    detailViewController.eventNameDetailView = ;


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am very sorry, i am a real beginner and this is also my first post.

Comment: Its not very clear that are you trying to do. Can you give more explanation?

Comment: The code is not complete. Therefore it is unclear what you want to do

Comment: @In my detailViewController i have created a .xib file with three labels (Event name, Event information and Creator name) The code that i am showing above is in my PFQueryTableViewController which is showing a tableview with events. When a row is selected in the tableview, it shows my detailViewController. So far so good. But i would like that the three labels will show the values of cell. I have created the UIlabel outlets. But i can't figure out how to change the text. I hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint the problem with only this snippet of code. The problem could be that the PFObject `object` does not contain the right data. There could also be an issue with the assignment of `cell.eventName.text = object[@"name"];`. Please be as specific as possible about the code you have right now, what is going wrong (***including any errors you may be getting or unexpected behavior***), and what you would like for the correct behavior to be

Comment: the code is not giving any errors.

Comment: the code is not giving any errors. cell.eventname.text is working well to show the Object value in the tableview in a cell. I want to implement code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, that when i select a row, the information should show in the labels of my detailviewcontroller. I tried :detailViewController.eventName = cell.eventname.text; and i also tried: detailViewController.eventName = object[@"name"]; and i also tried a couple of other things but it doesn't change the label(s) in the detailViewController.

Comment: I have a pfqueryTableView which shows a list of events. When i select an event it shows my detailViewController that i created in a .xib. Each row in the tableview shows an event name, event information and a name of the creator of the event. When an event is selected i want it to show the same information in my detailViewController.